# How to fix calendar issue in swift? (glad to see even in objective-c)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, calendar

I have used several methods of calendar instance. So, `isDateInToday()` and `isDateInTomorrow()` are main methods that have effect to UI part. Let's use `isDateInToday()` for today (my local time is 28th August, 2019 21:37:00 ), it shows the following:

00:00 - 4:59 (`false`). Here `isDateInTomorrow()` shows `true`

5:00 - 23:59 (`true`)

Calendar identifier is **gregorian**

Locale is **en_US**

timeZone is **GMT (secondsFromGMT=0)**

That's the calendar instance:

```swift
private var _calendar: Calendar = {
        var cal = Calendar.current
        cal.locale = Locale.current
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
        return cal
    }()
```

That's how I'm creating date:

```swift
public var today: Date? {
        let date = Date()

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.locale = .current
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)

        let formatterOut = DateFormatter()
        formatterOut.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatterOut.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru")
        formatterOut.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

        return formatterOut.date(from: dateString)
}
```

What should I do that it should show `true` for today between 00:00 and 23:59?

Comment: Use always the same `Calendar` instance for all calendar calculations.

Comment: Remove the timezone line from your code. You need to use the default timezone for the current calendar. Just use plain `Calendar.current.isDateInToday(yourDate)`

Comment: @vadian 
I'm using the same calendar instance

Comment: Apparently you don't.

Comment: @LeoDabus 
I have done in this way also, between 19:00 and 23:59 ``isDateInToday()`` shows ```false```. Time zone is +5:00 in my country (gmt)

Comment: @vadian

I have singleton class that called "CalendarManager", everywhere I'm using this class calendar instance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you are creating the `Date` instances that you are comparing?

Comment: @Paulw11 
I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have not found exact solution for this. But I have done it. I have created two date instances for today and tomorrow.

```swift
...
let today = Date()
...
let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)
```

And that's my solution for `isDateInToday()` and `isDateInTomorrow()`. I have ignored time.

```swift
func isDateInToday(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
    let year = calendar.compare(date, to: today, toGranularity: .year)
    let month = calendar.compare(date, to: today, toGranularity: .month)
    let day = calendar.compare(date, to: today, toGranularity: .day)
    return (year == .orderedSame && month == .orderedSame && day == .orderedSame)
}

func isDateInTomorrow(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
    let year = calendar.compare(date, to: tomorrow, toGranularity: .year)
    let month = calendar.compare(date, to: tomorrow, toGranularity: .month)
    let day = calendar.compare(date, to: tomorrow, toGranularity: .day)
    return (year == .orderedSame && month == .orderedSame && day == .orderedSame)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create date with your local time zone interval:

```swift
let seconds: TimeInterval = TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it